# Weird HTML <style> tag, does not have content but the style rule exists

Tags: javascript, html, css

First, Sorry for my bad English, I hope you can understand what I mean.

I wanna ask why these `style rule` exist when the style tag had no content, I had no Idea what is it.
These inspector screenshot was captured on [TransferWise](https://wise.com/user/account/) Dashboard,

---

[image: Image 1.]

Image 1.

---

On Image 1. (red) it has class `.css-1r17gmu` and had the rule `padding 24px, border-radius 0px, display flex, etc`, but when I click the style location reference (blue), the style tag had no content. (Image 2 - Below)

---

[image: Image 2]

Image 2.

---

I wanna copy the style to my project, but had no idea how is this, and how to create it,

When I try to `Delete-Undo` the style tag (Image 2, blue background), the tag remain the same, but the style is gone.

Thats my Question, I dont know if this has a duplicate since I dont know the keyword.

Comment: There's a lot of other `<style>` tags around

Comment: The other had it content, but `style[data-emotion=css]` had no content.

Comment: Looks weird. I can reproduce too.

Comment: @CertainPerformance are this has deal with javascript? I mean creating style rule without including it on the html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This effect can be achieved by inserting rules into the stylesheet with [`.insertRule`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSSStyleSheet/insertRule), which results in the rule on the `<style>` tag in question applying to elements in the DOM, but without inserting HTML markup into the `<style>` tag. You can see it on that site by selecting the style tag in the inspector, and then doing `console.dir($0.sheet.cssRules)` in the console:

[image]

If you want to copy the style contained there, you'll have to iterate over the `.cssRules`.

Live example of this behavior:

```js
document.querySelector('#theStyle').sheet.insertRule('.foo { background-color: yellow; }');
// Text content is still empty:
console.log(document.querySelector('#theStyle').textContent);
```

```html
<style id="theStyle"></style>
<div class="foo">foo</div>
```

Comment: Thanks that's work!, I don't know we can Rule the style without inserting it to markup, this is wonderful.

@CertainPerformance are this mean we can hide all of the style rule using the `.insertRule`, or it has a side effect like slowing user paint time?